# Improving inverse modulo via Euclidean algorithms

Tags: algorithm

Stuck with a question for Complexity class: "You are given a,b in Z_N* and want to complete a^-1 and b^-1 mod N. By now we know how to calculate it via using the Euclidean algorithm twice, with a,N and b,N. My question is that how can one do it with a single invocation of the Euclidean Algorithm (Finding the GCD) and 3 multiplications mod N?

Comment: You may have more luck on http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know the following (all congruences mod N)

```
a * b * (a * b)^-1 = 1

b * (a * b)^-1 = a^-1
a * (a * b)^-1 = b^-1
```

So if we calculate `(a * b)^-1`, the partial inverses `a^-1` and `b^-1` can be calculated with a multiplication.

Comment: Hmmm.... does make quite a lot of sense. But it's not any faster than the original idea is it?

Comment: Not sure. But I guess that executing the Euclidean algorithm is much slower than multiplication. Of course, this depends on the size of the numbers and if the multiplication can be performed with a few hardware instructions. Doesn't the extended Euclidean algorithm include multiplications as well?

Comment: Well the Euclidean algorithm seems to be O(log b) for the worst case (consecutive Fib. numbers).